# Taylor's Theorem: equality between the function and the infinite series

Tags: taylor-expansion

My understand of Taylor's theorem is:

> Let $f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ be $k+1$ times differentiable on the
>   open interval with $f^{(k)}$ continuous on the closed interval between
>   $a$ and $x$. Then
>       $f(x) = P_k(x) + R_k(x)$
>
> where
>
> $P_k(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 +
> \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$
>
> and
>
> $R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!}(x-a)^{k+1}$ where $c$ is between
>   $a$ and $x$.

At least this is one form of the theorem.

So if we apply this to something like $f(x)=e^x$ at $a=0,$ we get

$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + R_2(x)$

or

$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + + \frac{x^3}{3} + R_3(x)$

etc...

But I often see the equality $e^x$ with the infinite series $1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots$.

How is something like this achieved? Is it a consequence of Taylor's theorem? I suppose we need something like $\lim_{k \to \infty} R_k(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, that's all what those equalities mean.

Comment: An often not mentioned fact : It is not true that the Taylor series of every infinitely differentiable function converges  to the function at every point in the domain of the function. $e^x$ happens to be real analytic, and this is shown by explicit bounds on $R_k$ which crucially depend on the nature of $e^x$. For example, the infinitely differentiable function which is $e^{-\frac 1x}$ for $x > 0$ and zero elsewhere, has a Taylor series which is entirely zero at the point zero, and therefore does not approximate the function in a symmetric nieghbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Therefore, $\lim R_k \to 0$ happens precisely for real analytic functions, and asking when this happens is not a very easy question to answer, and depends very crucially on the nature of the function in question. That is why it's not mentioned as part of Taylor's theorem, since it's not even correct.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Then for this special of of $f(x)=e^x$, we still need to prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty} R_k(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$? This happens to be the case because, for fixed $x$, we have $\frac{f^{k+1}(c)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1} = \frac{e^c}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1} \to 0$?

Comment: @theQman Exactly. You often need to look at the function itself, to decide whether or not the remainder term converges or not. $e^x$ is well behaved, but you will notice that the function I gave isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor’s series are a special case of the more general case of Power series and you are correct, Taylor’s series is obtained by pointwise expansion which in general converge in an neighborhood of the expansion point but for some function it can converges for all x values (EG $e^x$, $\sin x$, $\cos x$...).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Any infinite series $a+b+c+d+e+\cdots$ is just a shorter notation for the sequence of the sums $$a,a+b,a+b+c,a+b+c+d,a+b+c+d+e,\cdots.$$ So whenever you see a series, what you should in fact think of is the sequence of partial sums. This series converges or not as the associated sequence converges or not, and the limit of the sequence is called the sum (an extension of the word as usually used) of the series.